# 2-form on a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $f:M$ $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable and $p\in M$ with $df(p)=0$. I am trying to show that the application,
$$\begin{matrix}\mathfrak{X}(M)\times \mathfrak{X}(M):&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\(V,W)&\rightarrow&V(W(f))(p)\end{matrix}$$
is symmetric. I manage to do some manipulations but I always end up coming back to the first expression.

Comment: Alright I noticed that it was as simple as showing that $[V,W](f)(p)=0$. Anyway if someone could provide a proof without using coordinates I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Use the fact that if $Z=[V,W]$, then $[V,W]f(p) = df(p).Z(p)$.

Comment: I was looking for a direct manipulation to show $V(W(f))(p)=W(V(f))(p)$ without using that $V(W)-W(V)$ is a vector field. Although now I think about it, it might not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that,
$$V(W(f))(p)-W(V(f))(p)=[V,W](p)(f)=df(p)[V,W]=0$$
so, $$V(W(f))(p)=W(V(f))(p)$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition of differential, for *any* vector field $W$, we have:
$$W_p f=df_p W_p=0$$so your form is not only symmetric, it is identically null.

My intuition is that a vector is a sort of partial derivative. But the *total* differential vanishes, so any partial derivative must also be zero.

Comment: No, the form isn't identically null. The form actually applies the vector $W(p)$ to the real function $V(f)(q)$, where $q$ is the variable. Wich is, in general, distinct from $f$.

Comment: $q\neq p$ ? There is something inconsistent in the definition...

Comment: Is not necesary that $q\neq p$, why do you think that? $V(f)$ is a function for all $q\in M$ into $\mathbb{R}$, so $W(V(f))$ is aswell a real map on $M$, which you can particularice on $p$.

Comment: Uhm... I see, I was confused by the notation. If you develop in coordinates and all the first order terms vanish, you obtain precisely the hessian (although strictly speaking defining the hessian would require a connection).